# How can I get hg to prompt for my HTTP auth username / password on cygwin / windows?

Tags: mercurial, push, authentication

At home, this works perfectly. I'm on another computer now (using cygwin) and hg push will not prompt for a username / password:

```
user@localhost /cygdrive/d/repos/upthescala/viewprotect
$ hg push https://viewprotect.googlecode.com/hg/
pushing to https://viewprotect.googlecode.com/hg/
searching for changes
abort: http authorization required
```

Here are the contents of my ~/.hgrc:

```
[http_proxy]
host=someproxy:8080

[ui]
username = My Name <myemail>
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Note: this seems to be a cygwin problem. When I try from the Windows prompt (cmd.exe), it works as expected:

```
D:\repos\upthescala\viewprotect>hg push https://viewprotect.googlecode.com/hg/
pushing to https://viewprotect.googlecode.com/hg/
searching for changes
http authorization required
realm: Google Code Mercurial Repository
user: myemailaddress
password: *********

remote: Success.
```

--
LES

Answer (score 8):

This could be caused by using a version of Mercurial that's tied to the Windows console subsystem.  The binary distributed with Tortoise falls into this category.  If this is the case, mercurial is expecting to use the console subsystem to prompt for credentials, but it does not find it when run from the Cygwin shell.  In my case, installing and using the Cygwin version of mercurial fixed the problem, in addition to fixing color output.  To check which version you're using, run 'which hg' (but you probably already knew that).

Comment: I have the same problem, but I use MSYS, not Cygwin. Any suggestions for me?

Comment: Can someone give this guy a medal!

Answer (score 8):

To add to Andrew's comment:

> installing and using the Cygwin version of mercurial fixed the problem,

This also fixed the problem for me, but it caused another problem which took me some time to figure out.  When using the Cygwin version of hg, all files that had been cloned under TortoiseHG showed up as modified when I ran `hg status`, but no differences were shown for any of them when I ran `hg diff`.

The problem was that the permissions didn't match.  Running `chmod 644 .* -R` in each repo resolved this problem.

Answer (score 6):

Since it's HTTP you can always put the username and password right in the URL.  That works on any website using http auth and in any browser.

```
hg push https://myemailaddress:*********@viewprotect.googlecode.com/hg/
```

Alternately, newer Mercurial versions have an [auth section](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth) you can use.

BTW, that's a terrible password.  You should come up with something better than eight stars.

Comment: of course, i blocked out the real password! (it's the crazily cryptic password that google generates for you for the source code repository -- i'm not that dense :)

Comment: lol @ "that's a terrible password. You should come up with something better than eight stars."

Comment: @HighCommander4 but guys, hey guys, it's actually NINE stars..! See? See?!? \*\*gets promptly booed off stage\*\*